# sklearn RFE with logistic regression

Tags: scikit-learn, logistic-regression, feature-extraction, feature-selection, rfe

I am trying to make a logistic regression model with [RFE](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFE.html#) feature selection.

```
weights = {0:1, 1:5}
model = LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs', max_iter=5000, class_weight=weights)
rfe = RFE(model, 25)
rfe_model = rfe.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(rfe_model.support_)
print(selector.ranking_)
```

And I get:

```
array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False, False])
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 4, 3, 2, 5])
```

How can I use `rfe_model.support_` to extract the list of chosen features (subset the data frame) and make a model with only those features (except manually, by making a for loop ad subsetting the list of features itself)? Is there a more elegant way?

Bonus question: Where can I find more info regarding feature selection for logistic regression (not including backward, forwards and stepwise method)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Pipeline](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) for this, like:

```
selector = RFE(LogisticRegression(), 25)
final_clf = SVC()
rfe_model = Pipeline([("rfe",selector),('model',final_clf)])
```

Now when you call `rfe_model.fit(X,y)`, `Pipeline` will first transform the data (i.e. select features) with `RFE` and send that transformed data to `SVC`. You can now also use `GridSearchCV`, `cross_validate` and all other sorts of built in functions on `rfe_model`.